# Django generating test data incredibly slow

Tags: python, django, postgresql, test-data

Django 1.8, Postgres 8.4.20

I'm trying to prepare some performance test data in DB - generating 100 000 Django Users as well as other model instances. Here is my code:

```
for n in range(100000):
    # Generate User with one related Profile
    user = User.objects.create(username=str(random.random()))
    UserProfile.objects.create(custom_id=str(random.random()), user=user)

    # For each User generate a Journey with 10 related Visits
    journey = Journey.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
    for i in range(10):
        journey.visit_set.add(Visit(custom_id=str(random.random())))

    # Also for each User generate a Progress with 100 related Challenges
    progress = Progress.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
    for j in range(100):
        progress.challenge_set.add(Challenge(custom_id=str(random.random())))
```

It works as expected, the only issue is that it is incredibly slow. On a VPS with 1 core and 1 Gb RAM it took 1 hour to generate just 4000 users with corresponding related entries.

The consumed CPU is about 10%, memory 200mb and the load average floats around 1.00.

How can I speed this up?

Comment: Try with [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Comment: DB on the same server as Django?  You could try doing for n in range(10000) and running the script 10 times in parallel

Comment: ok thanks. but why it's so slow now? is there any limits for a single django script populating the database?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary better idea than mine, though the manual does says it does not work with many-to-many relationships

Comment: You can also use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/), the idea being to generate xml or json files in order to load the data.

Comment: minor question that shouldn't have anything to do with the matter at hand, but are you running python 2.x or 3.x?  (For 2.x, you should really be using xrange instead of range, but doing range(100000) shouldn't be killing performance)

Comment: What password hasher are you using? Try using MD5 for testing/performance. PBKDF2/bcrypt are designed to be slow (to make cracking harder)

Comment: @Foon it's Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested in comments, I used [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and launched my script 10 times in parallel. This increased the speed to about 100 User entries per second, which was fine in my case.